# How to start numbering counter at Subsection?

Tags: numbering

I couldn't find this answer anywhere. So I want my `subsection` to start at 1, and then `subsubsection` follow with 1.1. At the moment, however `section` is also using counter therefore my `subsection` starts at 1.1 instead. What's the best way to skip counter at `section`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{float}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section*{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:intro}}
\subsection*{My subsection}
\section*{My section}
\label{sec:summ}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:summ}}
\subsection*{Findings Summary}
\newpage
\section*{My section}
\label{sec:find}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:find}}

\subsection{My subsection}
\subsubsection{My subsubsection}
\newpage
\section*{Appendices}
\label{sec:app}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:app}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}`, but I'm not sure I really understand the request...

Comment: @campa This solved the problem. Sorry if I didn't explain properly. Now instead of 1.1 I get 1, and instead of 1.1.1 I get 1.1, just like I wanted.